# Scrapy saving 200 status urls with empty items in a file

Tags: python, scrapy, pipeline

I notice in scrapy log that some urls returned 200 status but contained no items. It seems to be the stability of the site as re-crawling these urls 1-2 times again yield items. I would like to save these urls in a separate file for re-crawling.

I tried to create a dictionary in the spider class to store these urls but there is no easy way to save the dictionary into a file.

Another way I tried is to create a 2nd item class for urls and use item pipeline. It still outputs empty file though. I am not too advanced to write my own pipeline. Here is my code.

```
import scrapy
class MyItem(scrapy.Item):
   productCode = scrapy.Field()
   productName = scrapy.Field()
   ...

class UrlItem(scrapy.Item):
   eurl = scrapy.Field()
```

parse

```
class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    custom_settings = {
        'FEEDS':{
            '%(filename)s.csv':{'format':'csv', 'encoding':'utf-8',},
                },
        'FEED_EXPORTERS': {'csv': 'scrapy.exporters.CsvItemExporter',},}

    def parsePage(self, response):
        products = response.xpath(...)
        if len(products) == 0:
            url = UrlItem()
            url['eurl'] = response.url
            yield url
        else:
            item = MyItem()
            item['...'] = ...
            ...
            yield item
```

pipeline

```
from .items import MyItem, UrlItem
import csv
class UrlPipeline:
    def open_spider(self, spider):
        self.file = open('%s.csv' % "noProductsUrls", 'w')

    def close_spider(self, spider):
        self.file.close()

    def process_item(self, url, spider):
        if isinstance(url, UrlItem):
            csvWriter = csv.writer(self.file)
            csvWriter.writerow(ItemAdapter(url)) 

from itemadapter import ItemAdapter
from scrapy.exceptions import DropItem
class MyPipeline:
    def __init__(self):
        self.ids_seen = set()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
    
        if isinstance(item, MyItem):
            adapter = ItemAdapter(item)
            if adapter['productCode'] in self.ids_seen:
                raise DropItem(f"Duplicate item found: {item!r}")
            else:
                self.ids_seen.add(adapter['productCode'])
                return item
```

settings file

```
'project.pipelines.MyPipeline': 300,
'project.pipelines.UrlPipeline': 300,
```

The thing is also I have the exporter setting in spider class already that saves a csv. In the pipeline I just want to add one more csv. Do the two conflict? Or it is better to structure both csv files in the pipeline?

**Update:** I opted for @marcos solution below which is superior.

There is a way to save csv in the spider class which is based on [this post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/197518/writing-to-a-csv-file-in-a-customized-way-using-scrapy).

```
def __init__(self):
    self.outfile = open("urls.csv", "w", newline = "")
    self.writer = csv.writer(self.outfile)

def closed(self,reason):
    self.outfile.close()
```

add the following in def parse

```
if len(products) == 0:
    self.writer.writerow([response.url])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you just yield a retry request whenever no product is found on the page, unless you have a very specific reason to store those URLs.

The code would look like:

```
class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    custom_settings = {
        'FEEDS':{
            '%(filename)s.csv':{'format':'csv', 'encoding':'utf-8',},
                },
        'FEED_EXPORTERS': {'csv': 'scrapy.exporters.CsvItemExporter',},}

    def parsePage(self, response):
        products = response.xpath(...)
        if not len(products):
            yield self._retry_request(response)
            return

        item = MyItem()
        item['...'] = ...
        ...
        yield item

    def _retry_request(self, response, max_retries=5):
        retries = response.meta.get('retry_time', 0)
        if retries < max_retries:
            return response.request.replace(
                meta={**response.meta, 'retry_time': retries + 1},
                dont_filter=True,
            )
        else:
            self.logger.warning(f'Max retries reached for {response.url}')
```

Comment: This is an excellent suggestion. It saves me from manually running crawl again taking the urls from the file. It also solves me another issue of random empty page errors in the log. I did find a way to save the file in the spider class in the end which I will share below.